# Allow signed in users (subscribers) to see their drafts

Tags: user-roles, draft

I allow signed in users to post on my site using a form. They can also save drafts. However, their role doesn't allow them to actually see their drafts so they see a 404 page.

How can I allow them to see their drafts ? As admin, I can, but I need them to see it.

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer: change their role to author ann define in the settings that new users are automatically authors.